# Window slicing when loading glade file

Tags: c, xml, file, window, glade

I have a problem where when I close glade and reopen glade and the glade file, the window slices up a little one top for no reason:

[Before closing and reopening glade and loading the file]
[image]

[After closing and reopening glade and loading the file]
[image]

There doesn't seem to be any parameter that could have changed that, I mean the problem still occurs on brand new bland windows